# Mypoint java not working with user input

Tags: java

Hi I have to write a program that creates the two points and calculates the distance between them ... I have written the program but not I have to do it with user input .... can someone please tell me where I am going wrong ?

```
class MyPoint {

    private double x;
    private double y;

    public double getx()
    {
        return x;
    }
    public double gety()
    {
        return y;
    }
    public MyPoint()
    {

    }

    public MyPoint(double x, double y)
    {
         this.x = x;
         this.y = y;
    }
    public double distance(MyPoint secondPoint) {
        return distance(this, secondPoint);
      }

      public static double distance(MyPoint p1, MyPoint p2) {
        return Math.sqrt((p1.x - p2.x) * (p1.x - p2.x) + (p1.y - p2.y)
            * (p1.y - p2.y));
      }
}

public class MyPointTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
           MyPoint p1 = new MyPoint(0,0);
           MyPoint p2 = new MyPoint(10, 30.5);
           p1.distance(p2);
           System.out.println("Distance between two points (0,0) and (10,30.5)= "+MyPoint.distance(p1,p2));
        }
}
```

This is what I have tried with user input

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestMyPoint {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        MyPoint p1 = new MyPoint();
            MyPoint p2 = new MyPoint();
        System.out.print("Enter a  first point  " + p1 );
        System.out.print("Enter a  second point  " + p2 );
        System.out.println(p1.distance(p2));
        System.out.println(MyPoint.distance(p1, p2));

    }

}
```

Comment: What do you get as output?

Comment: Enter a  first point  MyPoint@49c7e176Enter a  second point  MyPoint@61a32fd132.09750769140807
32.09750769140807

Comment: "*I have to do it with user input*" so why are you not reading data from user?

Answer (score 2):

Scanner is imho a good start.
Try something like:

```
System.out.println("Please enter x of the first point:");
double x1 = input.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Please enter y of the first point:");
double y1 = input.nextDouble();
MyPoint p1 = new MyPoint(x1, y1);
...
```